# how to remotely zip files using putty

Tags: remote-access, compression

Is there a way to remotely ZIP up files using Putty the same way you can ZIP up files using Remote Desktop on another machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on what's installed on the host that you're connecting to - whether you connect via SSH (PuTTY) to a Unix/Linux machine or RDP to a Windows machine.

Try running zip, gzip, bzip, or tar - those are usually installed on most Unix machines.

Answer (score 0):

as mfinni says, it requires that zip is installed on the remote system. Assuming that you are on a unix system and that zip is already installed, the command to unzip a file is:

```
unzip myzipfile.zip
```

Comment: Check the manpage for zip (man zip).  

You can do something like this:
zip output.zip file1 file2 ...

Comment: absolutely, but the question was to zip up a files, aka unzip :)

Answer (score -1):

You can also ZIP folders using Putty just like this:

```
zip -r filename.zip foldername
```

Its very useful when you want to backup and download folders with a lot of files.

Comment: This *only works* if the system has `zip` installed on it as two others have already pointed out.